# Installing Django using pip and virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip

I am trying to install Django using virtualenv together with pip on mac and I am facing some problem in installing it. I am basically following this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71Ja7L89EOA to install Django.

I got stuck when I type .env/bin/activate like in the video

Error msg:

```
APPLEs-iMac-2:~ IMAC$ .env/bin/activate
-bash: .env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

What might be doing wrong? Shld i do inside the project file and i can't do in the main folder is it?

Need some help on it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a space. command `source` is equal to `.`
The correct is `. env/bin/activate`

Comment: u mean there should be a space between . and env?